# Using chain rule on a function $u:\mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Suppose we have  $x \in \mathbb R^n$, $\lambda \in \mathbb R$ and a function $u:\mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R$. I want to calculate the derivative $$
\frac{\partial u(\lambda x)}{\partial \lambda}
$$
So if we define $h(\lambda) =u(\lambda x) $ then by chain rule
$$
\frac{dh}{d \lambda} = D_{(\lambda x)} u(\lambda x) \cdot D_\lambda[\lambda x]=\nabla u \cdot D_\lambda[\lambda x]
$$
Now I think $D_\lambda[\lambda x]$ is a Jacobian $n \times n$ matrix with $x$ at each row, since $\lambda x$ is a function $\mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R^n$. However, the proposed solution to this problem says that the answer is just $$\nabla u \cdot x$$
What am I missing?

Comment: $D_\lambda$ is a derivative with respect to a scalar variable, so when applied to a vector-valued function the result is still vector-valued, not matrix-valued.

Comment: @Ian I see. Thank you.